# find string with regular expression in load runner 12.5 extractor

Tags: regex, performance-testing, loadrunner

I use load runner 12.5 to record script . I want to extract a value in response script and pass it to other so I want to find 17821107849674 in script with regular expression. what should I do?

```
.
.
.
 AdfLoopbackUtils.runLoopback(
     9,
     '_afrLoop',
     '17821107849674',
     '_afrWindowMode',
     'Adf-Window-Id',
     '_afrPage',
     '',
     'w0',
     ';EBOXPORTALID=3fUCuSHtu2lAMvjhIqj5GMCRNrUTXZ_E0w-nQGzQxolJ4T38oItW!-939378123',
     '!',
     false,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loadrunner should be using [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) as the default regex engine.

So you could look for 14 digits surrounded by word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b(\d{14})\b
```

Or more precisely, look for 14 digits and lookaround for single quotes :

```
(?<=\')(\d{14})(?=\')
```

To be even more precise and check if it's followed by that _afrWindowMode:

```
((?<=\')[0-9]+(?=\',\s*\'_afrWindowMode\'))
```

Comment: i just found that number of digit is Variable so i need to find a variable always preceded by "'_afrLoop'," and followed by ",'_afrWindowMode but i found that the number of digit is Variable. i need exact value without

Comment: @Mahsaehsani  Try with the regex `\'_afrLoop\',\s+\'\K\d+(?=\',\s+\'_afrWindowMode\')`.  To check what it does you could try it in an online regex tester for PCRE, for example [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: load runner message : " The current expression is not valid."

Comment: Oh well, I don't know loadrunner.  Maybe the regex engine doesn't know the `\K` after all.   And most regex engine don't allow a non-fixed regex in a lookbehind.  Maybe you could just assume that the number is always followed by _aftWindowMode.  Does `(?<=\')\d+(?=\',\s*\'_afrWindowMode\')` work?

Comment: thank you , but it still has error :" No matches for the expression were found in the recorded response."

Comment: @Mahsaehsani Then I'm out of ideas. Maybe your search method only looks line by line, not multiline.  And those words are on other lines.

Comment: I found the problem , just need add parentheses before and after your last answer .((?<=\')[0-9]+(?=\',\s*\'_afrWindowMode\')) .please add your comment as an answer .

Comment: @Mahsaehsani Huh. So your search method needs a capture group for it to work? Well, good that you found it then.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us more about the pattern?   Is it always the third element in the set?  Is it always preceded by "'_afrLoop'," or followed by ",'_afrWindowMode'?"

You potentially have several paths to collect the value, but understanding the patterns involved helps

Comment: yes it always preceded by "'_afrLoop'," and followed by ",'_afrWindowMode but i found that the number of digit is Variable. i need exact value without ' '

Comment: look at web_reg_save_param_ex() with a fixed LB and RB condition.  It will capture all in between.  You can include the single quotes in your LB and RB conditional

http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/12.53/help/function_reference/Content/web/lrFr_web_reg_save_param_ex.htm